# How to calculate current velocity using Euler integration

Tags: physics, timedelta

I want to know if I convert formula correctly. I'm not sure of that.

I know:

**force** = **mass** * **acceleration**

**acceleration** = (**Velocity** - **previousVelocity**) / **deltaTime**

**acceleration** = **force** / **mass**

So:

(**Velocity** - **previousVelocity**) / **deltaTime** = **Force** / **Mass**

If I know the force to apply , the mass , deltaTime and previousVelocity, to convert it in the new velocity for a euler integration? This formula is correct ?:

**Velocity** = (**Force** / **mass** * **deltaTime**) + **previousVelocity**

I feel like something is wrong or missing, I need the real formula.

thanks a lot!

Comment: force != mass * velocity / deltatime

Comment: @Sancho Ooopps ... where is the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've written is Forward Euler on dv/dt = f(t) (with m=1) ... i.e. v(n+1) = v(n) + f(n) * dt.

Comment: And this will be exactly correct if the force is constant.

Comment: yes but where the mass is inserted in the formula. I absolutly need it.

Comment: You can rescale time (change of variables) ...  tau = t/m, if you don't like saying m=1.

Comment: Sorry , probably because I'm tired or my math/physics knowledge is not high , but I don't see where is the mass in : v(n+1) = v(n) + f(n) * dt

Comment: @mathtick I edited my question a bit. What did you think about my reflexion now. My formula seem to be correct and exactly what you wrote ? I understand now I think when you say "m = 1".